# Import from Bitbucket to Gitlab fails

Tags: bitbucket, gitlab, raspberry-pi2, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab on my Raspberry Pi 2 B using Let's encrypt certificates.
I configured the bitbucket oauth as described here ([Tutorial](http://stratus3d.com/blog/2015/09/06/migrating-from-bitbucket-to-local-gitlab-server/)).

**Problem**:
The first import by an existing repo from bitbucket to gitlab succeeds, but when I try importing another repos, it fails.
Another strange thing is, that the "Import all projects" Button is always loading regardless I am importing or not.
*New: The first import process after gitlab-ctl restart succeeds.*

**Question**:
Is there any way to find details about why the import failed in detail? The production.log does not contain something helpful.
Why does one import process succeed after restarting gitlab?

**Things I tried**:

- 3x redoing the methods exactly described in the tutorial above (incl. new SSH Keys and new API Keys)
- changing timeouts in gitlab.rb
- CPU and RAM usage is normal and do not exceed the limits
- restarting gitlab, restarting server etc. (After restart one import process succeeds)

**My Configuration**:

- Raspberry Pi

  - A 900MHz quad-core ARM Cortex-A7 CPU
  - 1GB RAM
  - Raspbian on 64GB USB 3.0 Stick
  - Gitlab

    - GitLab 8.7.3
    - GitLab Shell 2.7.2
    - GitLab API v3
    - Git 2.7.4
    - Ruby 2.1.8p440
    - Rails 4.2.6
    - PostgreSQL 9.2.15
  - Let's encrypt SSL Certificates

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this to the gitlab developers and they fixed this problem in version 8.7.6

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/17376